# CSS a:hover moving text

Tags: css

I am having issues with text moving them I hover over the element. It is working fine until you hover over it.

So just to clarify you run the mouse over the text and the background colour and everything changes correctly, just the text moved higher than origional text.

This is the CSS code I have for this element:

```
 #top_login_panel ul.menu_topPanel li.item-8 {
        background: url("../images/menu/top-panel-login-bg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0);
        height: 43px;
        width: 145px;
    }
    #top_login_panel ul.menu_topPanel li.item-8 a {
        width: 145px;
    }
    #top_login_panel ul.menu_topPanel li.item-8 a:hover {
      background-image: url("../images/menu/top-panel-login-bg1.png") !important;    
      background-position: center center !important;    
      background-repeat: no-repeat !important;    
      color: hsl(0, 1%, 25%);     
      margin-left: -3px;    
      margin-top: -8px; 
      width: 114px; 
    }
    #top_login_panel ul.menu_topPanel li.item-8 a {
        display: block;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 22px 0 0 35px;
    }
```

Can you please advice how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Its in a Joomla website so not sure how to show that... sorry

Comment: Of course the element moves when you hover it... You specifically are changing the size and positioning of it in the `:hover` styles: `margin-left: -3px; margin-top: -8px; width: 114px;`. Try removing and/or adjusting these and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Sathish S I used the moving of the elements but then just placed the padding in a different location and that worked.

```
#top_login_panel ul.menu_topPanel li.item-8 a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: -3px;    
  margin-top: -12px; 
  width: 114px;
}


#top_login_panel ul.menu_topPanel li.item-8 a:hover {
  background-image: url("../images/menu/top-panel-login-bg1.png") !important;    
  background-position: center center !important;    
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;    
  color: hsl(0, 1%, 25%);   
}

#top_login_panel ul.menu_topPanel li.item-8 a {
   padding: 31px 0 0 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the **hover block of CSS code** has **properties and values** that **the normal state doesn't have** so it moves as the new properties are applied. Let the color be the only difference if you don't want it to move.

```css
li.item-8 a {
        background-image: url("../images/menu/top-panel-login-bg1.png") !important;    
      background-position: center center !important;    
      background-repeat: no-repeat !important;      
      margin-left: -3px;    
      margin-top: -8px; 
      width: 114px; 
    }
 li.item-8 a:hover {
      background-image: url("../images/menu/top-panel-login-bg1.png") !important;    
      background-position: center center !important;    
      background-repeat: no-repeat !important;    
      color: hsl(0, 1%, 25%);     
      margin-left: -3px;    
      margin-top: -8px; 
      width: 114px; 
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item-8"><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li class="item-8"><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li class="item-8"><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li class="item-8"><a href="#">One</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.,

```
 #top_login_panel ul.menu_topPanel li.item-8 a:hover {
      background-image: url("../images/menu/top-panel-login-bg1.png") !important;    
      background-position: center center !important;    
      background-repeat: no-repeat !important;    
      color: hsl(0, 1%, 25%);     
    }
    #top_login_panel ul.menu_topPanel li.item-8 a {
        display: block;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 22px 0 0 35px;
        margin-left: -3px;    
        margin-top: -8px; 
        width: 114px; 
    }
```

I changed the `margin` property to `a` tag